# how to install Kundli 2002 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, installation

I tried to install kundli 2002 on Windows7 with administrative privileges, its installed
but still its not working properly, then I tried to set compatibility with windows xp,
but still it doesn't work properly,

It makes windows7 Hanged and with 50% of CPU usage, but nothing actually works.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** kundli 2002 has compatibility issue with all windows OSs higher XP. It will not work with Windows 7,vista or 8/8.1
I am using same software and done much research on the same problem. The solution that worked for was to Install XP as VM and then install kundli on the VM. I have installed kundli software same way first in windows 7 and recently on windows 8.1 tablet.

Alternatively you can use kundli 2009 which is a better program and works on Windows 7.

Comment: It is not installing properly with wine 1.6, Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option you can try:

1. Remove the installed program.
2. You already know how to set a program for compatibility mode -- set that mode on the setup.exe, then start setup.exe.
3. Once installed, set the mode on the installed program too.
4. If that works, you can try to remoev the mode again, perhaps it still works.

Comment: I tried this way too, but not succeed ...